# ATM Cash Option (Notes) Algorithm

Tags: ruby

I am developing an ATM exercise in Ruby that one of the functionalities is that after requesting the cash value the system can display options for possible cash flow.

**Ex: R$120**

- 2x R$50 e 1x R$20
- 2x R$50 e 2x R$10
- 1x R$100 e 2x R$20
- 6x R$20
- 12x R$10
- etc...

These notes are limited, that is, if in the box I only have 10 notes of 10, then the option of 12x $ 10 will not appear.

I found a possible algorithm in Java, but I find it too complex ...

[ATM algorithm of giving money with limited amount of bank notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128759/atm-algorithm-of-giving-money-with-limited-amount-of-bank-notes)

My code so far is just that:

**main.rb**

```
# Constantes
LIMITE_SAQUE = 2000

# Variáveis
opcao = nil

saldo_atual = 5000

qtd_notas_cem = 20
qtd_notas_cinquenta = 100
qtd_notas_dez = 200
qtd_notas_vinte = 50


while opcao != 4 

# Exibe as opções do Caixa Eletrônico
puts "Qual operação você deseja?"
puts "1 - Saque"
puts "2 - Recarga de Notas"
puts "3 - Exibir Informações"
puts "4 - Sair"
puts ""

opcao = gets.to_i

case opcao
  when 1
    puts "Você escolheu a opção de Saque"
    puts "Infome o valor para saque: "
    valor = gets.to_i

    if valor <= saldo_atual && valor <= LIMITE_SAQUE
      saldo_atual = saldo_atual - valor
      puts ""
      puts "Saque efetuado no valor de R$#{valor}"
      puts "Saldo atual diponível: R$#{saldo_atual}"
      puts "" 
    elsif valor >= LIMITE_SAQUE
      puts ""
      puts "Limite de saque é superior a R$2000,00"
      puts ""
    else
      puts ""
      puts "Não existe valor dispónivel para saque."
      puts ""
    end

  when 2
    puts "Você escolheu a opção de Recarga"
    puts "Infome o valor da nota: "
    valorNota = gets.to_i

    puts "Informe agora a quantidade de notas: "
    qtdNotas = gets.to_i

  when 3
    puts "Você escolheu a opção de Informações"
  when 4
    puts "Sair..."
    %x(exit)
  else
    puts ""
    puts "!!!!!! Opçao escolhida inválida. !!!!!!"
    puts ""
  end
end
```

Comment: You’re gonna want this to be in English to get a useful response, otherwise you’ll have better luck in a language-specific site. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/393723

Comment: First of all, don't create piles of unrelated variables. Programming is primarily about manipulating data structures. For example, `quantity = { 1 => 20, 5 => 100, 10 => 200, 20 => 50 }` defines things in terms of numbers and numbers alone.  Another thing you'll want to do is indent properly and consistently. This helps convey structure and intent, two important things to help us help you with your code.

Comment: Algorithmically you want to take that `quantity` structure and deduct the largest possible amount from the desired total, and repeat. So 100 could be 5x20. If you run out of 20s, switch to 10s and so on. If you run out, return nothing. You can return in the same structure you're given, like 100 becomes `{ 20 => 5 }` or perhaps `{ 20 => 4, 10 => 2 }` if you're running low.

Comment: If you find yourself using that structure frequently, then wrap that into a class so you can build convenience methods on it. That's the Ruby way.

Comment: @tadman, I think you've misunderstood the question (as I did, in the same way, when I first read it). The OP wants to present a selection of choices to the customer for how they want their money. For example, maybe they don't want any $R100 notes, or 10 $R10 notes, and so on. See my answer for a fuller discussion.

Comment: @anothermh, in this case it's only the prompts and variable names that are not in English, so I don't see that as much of an impediment to understanding what is being asked. On the other hand, the OP's English is obviously good, so it wouldn't be hard to convert those bits to English.

Answer (score 2):

**Inventory and priority**

First, let's suppose the array `avail` contains the number of each note stored in the machine. For example,

```
avail = [[100, 3], [50, 4], [20, 8], [10, 2], [5, 4], [1, 12]]
```

Moreover we can interpret this as providing a priority over which notes are dispensed. This order of the elements would mean that as many $R100 notes as possible, up to 3, should be dispensed, then as many $R50 notes as possible, up to 4, and so on. On the other hand, if $R100 notes were to be dispensed only if there were an insufficient number of $R50 notes, one could write

```
avail = [[50, 4], [100, 3], [20, 8], [10, 2], [5, 4], [1, 12]]
```

There are situations, however, when all available notes cannot be used. If, for example,

```
avail = [[50, 3], [100, 1]]
```

and $R200 were desired, only 2 $R50 notes could be dispensed, even though 3 are available.

**Customer selects note combination preference**

Depending on the choice made by the customer, an array needs to be derived from `avail`, which I've termed `avail_mod` below. Here are some examples (all assuming a valid combination can be obtained).

*1 $R100 note:*

```
[[100, 1], [50, 4], [20, 8], [10, 2], [5, 4], [1, 12]]
```

*3 $50 notes:*

```
[[50, 3], [100, 3], [20, 8], [10, 2], [5, 4], [1, 12]]
```

*5 $R20 and 2 $5 notes:*

```
[[20, 8], [5, 2], [100, 3], [50, 4], [10, 2], [1, 12]]
```

This last array, for example, can be derived from `avail` as follows.

```
[[20, 8], [5, 2]] + avail.reject { |k,_| [20, 5].include?(k) }
  #=> [[20, 8], [5, 2], [100, 3], [50, 4], [10, 2], [1, 12]]
```

It's up to you to decide what possibilities are in the list presented to the customer and how `avail` is to modified for each choice.

**Code to compute a combination of notes for a given customer preference**

Given a total amount of cash desired, `amt`, and a modified array `avail_mod`, the following method can be used to determine the numbers of each note to dispense.

```
def dispense(amt, avail_mod)
  (d, n), *rest = avail_mod
  if rest.empty?
    return { d=>0 } if amt.zero?
    return nil if (amt % d) > 0 || d*n < amt
    return { d=>amt/d }
  end 
  last = nil
  m = [n, amt/d].min.downto(0).find { |m| last = dispense(amt-m*d, rest) }
  m.nil? ? nil : { d=>m }.merge(last)
end
```

This method employs a technique called [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). It is guaranteed to find a combination of notes that total `amt`, if one exists, subject to the array `avail_mod`. I've written it to give preference to greater numbers of notes of higher denominations. If, for example, $R588 is desired and the numbers of $R100 and $R50 notes given by `avail_mod` are respectively 4 and 6, it will first look for a solution using 4 $R100 notes, then 3 $R50 notes, and so on.

**Examples**

Suppose:

```
avail =     [[100, 3], [50, 4], [20, 8], [10, 2], [5, 4], [1, 12]] 
avail_mod = [[100, 2], [50, 4], [20, 8], [10, 2], [5, 4], [1, 12]
```

Then

```
spew_out = dispense(533, avail_mod)
  #=> {100=>2, 50=>4, 20=>6, 10=>1, 5=>0, 1=>3}  
spew_out.sum { |k,v| k*v }  
  #=> 533

dispense(300, avail_mod)
  #=> {100=>2, 50=>2, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0, 1=>0} 

dispense(0, avail_mod)
  #=> {100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0, 1=>0}

dispense(827, avail_mod)
  #=> nil

dispense(200, [[50,3], [100, 3]])
  #=> {50=>2, 100=>1}
```

**Update `avail`**

```
avail.map! { |d,n| [d, n-spew_out[d]] }
  #=> [[100, 1], [50, 0], [20, 2], [10, 1], [5, 4], [1, 9]]
```